# How to connect react-native with actioncable

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native, actioncable

how do you connect react-native to actioncable?
I've tried using `react-native-actioncable` doing the same implementation in the web-side but it's not working. I might be doing something wrong.

This is a sample code in my react native

```
  componentDidMount () {
    const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable?token=ryGj')
    cable.subscriptions.create('NasanaChannel', {
        received(data) {
          console.log('Received data:', data)
        }   
    })  
  }
```

```

But in logs it doesn't console.log anything. 
It has no error it just doesn't connect. In my rails server there's no connection happening.

Everything is fine with my web-side in react. But in mobile react-native it just won't connect.

I've tried a lot of implementation such as using an actioncable provider but alas no luck.

*This is on Android*

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming the url is correct, what would you expect to receive? Have you tried:

```
cable.subscriptions.create('NasanaChannel', {
    connected() {
      console.log('connected')
    }   
})
```